# Get remainder only from a division using PHP

Tags: php

I am dividing `19/5` where by I have used `19/5` but I am unable to get the remainder **only**.

How do I get it.

Comment: Why is 19 % 5 not returning what you're after - this should return 4.

Comment: That returns the rounded off value which is 4

Comment: @Jean: but that's exactly the remainder of 19 divided by 5. Also, why did you roll back my edit of your typo?

Comment: I am using 19/5 not 19%5

Comment: 4 is the remainder. It isn't rounded off.

Comment: @Jean: if you want to find the remainder of a division operation just use `%`.

Comment: @Jean: Maybe you should give a concrete example. Show us for which two numbers you want to get which value. Maybe you just used the wrong term and what you want is not the *remainder* .

Comment: I can use explode(".",$divided_value); to get anything after "." but is there a function by which I do not have the use the above

Comment: @Jean: please see Mark Baker's or mattbasta's answers.

Comment: @boltclock I saw the answers, but is there a math function to do the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Please try it-

```
  $tempMod = (float)($x / $y);
  $tempMod = ($tempMod - (int)$tempMod)*$y;
```

Comment: Complicated and slow

Answer (score 102):

```
echo 19 % 5;
```

should return 4, which is the remainder of 19/5 (3 rem 4)
There is no need to use floor, because the result of a modulus operation will always be an integer value.

If you want the remainder when working with floating point values, then PHP also has the fmod() function:

```
echo fmod(19,5.5);
```

**EDIT**

If you want the remainder as a decimal:

either

```
echo 19/5 - floor(19/5);
```

or

```
echo (19 % 5) / 5
```

will both return 0.8

Comment: I need only the decimal value

Comment: For the record, the last technique mentioned is the fastest, as there are fewer floating point operations being performed.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? We need a PHP function to show the logic for why the best answer is not accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what language you're using, `%` may not be the modulus operator. I'll assume you're using PHP, in which case it is `%`.

From what I can see, there is no need to use `floor()` with integer modulus, it will always return an integer. You can safely remove it.

To me, it looks like it isn't the math that's giving you hell, it's the code around it. You'll need to post more code; the code you have listed is fine.

**Edit:**

You're not looking for the remainder, you're looking for the left over decimal value. It has no name.

```
$leftover = 19 / 5;
$leftover = $leftover - floor($leftover);
```

This should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I need only the decimal value

Comment: It's called the fraction.