# PHP: How to check if number is a power of ten?

Tags: php, numbers

I need to check if a number is a power of ten (1, 10, 100, -1, -0.1, -0.01 etc.). Is there a way to do that in PHP ?

I tried
`((log10($num) % 1 === 0))`
because that worked in JS, but this is always true...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's apparently fixed in PHP 8 but throws an error  - https://3v4l.org/kE761 . This page has more information on that error, and probably why it's broken in PHP 7 - https://php.watch/versions/8.1/deprecate-implicit-conversion-incompatible-float-string

Comment: Thank you for you input aynber. Does that mean that there is no way to do that with PHP 8 ?

Comment: There's [fmod](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php) which is meant for decimals.

Comment: This link night help, couple ways to handle remainder with decimals. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272987/19070801

Comment: Thank you aynber, fmod did the trick ;)